# Print dereferencing array inside hash of hash of array

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

My data structure looks like

```
%foo (
   'bar' => HASH(0x1staddr)
)
```

HASH(0x1staddr) is

```
%moo = (
   'doe' => ARRAY(0x2ndaddr)
    )
```

ARRAY(0x2ndaddr) points to
    str1 str2 str3 str4 str5

How can I dereference that ARRAY(0x2ndaddr) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So really,

```
%foo = ( 'bar' => { 'doe' => [ 'str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5' ] } ) ;
```

First, I'd check out `Data::Dumper` which would print out all the levels of the structure for you without you having to put them back together.

Second, you can dereference multiple levels in one line:

```
print "$foo->{bar}{doe}[0]\n" ;
```

would print:

```
str1
```

Comment: Yes! Data::Dumper clearly showed me how my hash table looked like.